# Lock handling of scroll event in UIScrollView subview (inside a UIScrollView superview)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, uicollectionview, swipe

I have a complex view hierarchy:

```
UIScrollView
    - UITableView
        - UICollectionView
```

The `UICollectionView` and `UIScrollView` both scroll horizontally. Now, I want to capture the swipe gesture exclusively on `UICollectionView` so that the superview (`UIScrollView`) ignores it.

User can swipe left to get to the end of `UICollectionView`. When at the end, the swipe gesture on `UICollectionView` is ignored and captured by the superview (`UIScrollView`) and the interface changes. How can I prevent that from happening?

Note: I'm using the default swipe functionality provided by both UIScrollView and UICollectionView i.e. I'm not adding any custom swipe gesture handling.

Comment: you can use the delegate methods of UIScrollView, inside them you can recognize/decide which scrollView will be able to scroll

Comment: you can use the scrollEnable property to decide

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   scrollView.delegate = self;
   collectionView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   if (the scrollView didn't reached the end){
      then collectionView can't scroll
   }else{
      collectionView can scroll
   }
}
```

You can check to see if the `scrollView` reached the end with the `contentOffset` property

Don't forget to declare that you are using the delegate of scrollView

Hope that helps